# echo output while running script in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to output json string during execution of script.I am working on CI 3.

sleep has been used for simulation.I am calling this from jquery ajax.Also I have **used "progress" event listener on xhr.**

I have gone through search engine for the solution but nothing helped.

```
Controller class{
  public function show_status()
    {
         while(ob_get_level()!=0){
                   ob_end_flush();
          }

     ob_start();


        for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
        {
            echo $i;
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(2);       
        }
        echo 'done';
        ob_end_flush();   
    }
}
```

o/p=>

1 
2{after 3 seconds}
3{after 3 seconds}
.
.
.

Comment: i have tried a similar type of implementation before, but it seems like php doesn't work that way. even if you echo multiple times all the output will get flashed in the screen at once in a single response. if you have flexibility try using nodejs it is good at handling these scenarios. incase if you find a way to achieve what you wanted using PHP please donot forget to post it here.

Comment: This works fine when I implement in core php but for CI it fails

Comment: Made a little correction to my code!